# how to work with variables in files instead of memory in c#(like pagefile)

Tags: c#, virtual-memory, pagefile

I have written a program that I have to save large data in the variables.
how can I use files instead of memory? like virtual memory (page file)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) for this. In .NET Framework this nice feature is available since version `4.0`.

See Non-persisted memory-mapped files

> Non-persisted files are memory-mapped files that are not associated
>   with a file on a disk. When the last process has finished working with
>   the file, the data is lost and the file is reclaimed by garbage
>   collection. These files are suitable for creating shared memory for
>   inter-process communications (IPC).

Comment: Thanks for your interest.I have seen this before,but I have to use .Net 3.5.is there an alternative method?